# Copying rows from one table to another

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a table in excel containing 1000 rows and 10 columns.
How can I copy every 7th row from this table to a new table whose first row will be this 7th row, second row will be that table 14th row and so on.

I have never done these kind of things in excel before.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with plain Excel (no VBA). Add two columns at the end of your table. The first being a count of the line, the second flagging if the line count is divisible by 7 - I used the formula =IF(MOD(D4,7)=0,"Divisible by 7", "-").

[image]

Then filter the table on the 'Mark every 7th item' column, and copy and paste to new table.

Answer (score 1):

You need a macro. Press alt + F11

Basically you run that macro that goes like this

```
sub Copyer()
dim I as integer
Dim K as integer
I = 7
K = 1
while (Activesheet.Range("A" & I ).Value <> "")
 DestinationSheet.Range("A" & K ).Value = Activesheet.Range("A" & I).Value
K = K + 1
I = I + 7
Loop
End Sub
```

Code may need some grooming but that's the idea